# Picking Symbology and size for zXing.Net for speed and accuracy A4 black and white scan image

Tags: c#, barcode

I'm using zXing.Net to decode barcode in image (which is a scan of an A4 page using a black and white sheet-fed scanner).

The library supports the following barcodes according to it's documentation:
http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

**The following barcodes are supported by the decoder:**
UPC-A, UPC-E, EAN-8, EAN-13, Code 39, Code 93, Code 128, ITF, Codabar, MSI, RSS-14 (all variants), QR Code, Data Matrix, Aztec and PDF-417.

I have control of which barcodes we use.
I'm wondering if people can give me best practise for the following.

Best symobology/barcode to use for

- Speed
- Accuracy

Here is some sample data I'm trying to encode (text is typically this length or a couple of digits longer):

- 121065131160013
- 121065141160013
- 121065151160013
- 121065161160013
- 121065171160013

And also what is the best size the barcode should be on the A4 page.

I've also asked this on the codeplex discussion: https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/discussions/484057

Comment: How much and what type of data are you encoding? Can you give some sample values?

Comment: I've edited question with sample data.